# Pure virtuals and good practice

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, polymorphism

#### EDIT

`Handler(Accelerometer &a): acc(a){}` would be the proper way of assigning the reference and `Accelerometer &acc` would be the proper way to define the reference member.

## Background

The problem:

1. A class, `Handler`, relies on some function `void doThing()` of a member `acc`.
2. `Handler` is passed a reference to `acc` which is instantiated externally. `Handler` does not care about `acc` as long as `void doThing()` is implemented.

I'm after a way of ensuring that `doThing()` is implemented and allows the base class to be used.

The way I've managed to implement this is to use a pointer to the Base class `Accelerometer` which avoids issues with missing vtables and implementations. The code, however, does not work if `AccSensor` is passed by reference rather than by pointer.
The basis of my question is:

1. Why does this occur? I assume it's due to the compiler knowing that the pointer does not necessarily have something defined at its location at compile time and hence will not try to link associated methods and hence bypasses checks for instantiation of pure virtuals. I'm not sure my understanding is correct though and a more in-depth justification would be appreciated.
2. Is my implementation considered "good practice", and if not, do you have any suggestions for suitable alternatives?

## Code which compiles (and works)

```
class Accelerometer
{
public:
    virtual void doThing()=0;
};
```

```
class AccSensor: public Accelerometer
{
    void doThing(){std::cout << "doThing\n"; }
};
```

```
class Handler
{
private:
    Accelerometer* acc;
public:
    Handler(Accelerometer *a){ acc = a; }
    void someFunc(){ acc->doThing(); }
};
```

```
int main()
{
    AccSensor acc;
    Handler h(&acc);
    h.someFunc();
    return 0;
}
```

## Code which DOES NOT compile

```
class Handler
{
private:
    Accelerometer acc;
public:
    Handler(Accelerometer &a){ acc = a; }
    void someFunc(){ acc.doThing(); }
};
```

```
int main()
{
    AccSensor acc;
    Handler h(&acc);
    h.someFunc();
    return 0;
}
```

And for obvious reasons. One cannot instantiate a pure virtual. So this code would never work.
You could then try to use a plain virtual with:

```
class Accelerometer
{
public:
    virtual void doThing();
};
```

But this compiles with missing vtables and undefined references due to the lack of definition of `void doThing()`. To remedy this a method could be provided and possibly contain a throw to indicate a lack of override but that seems a little convoluted.

As a result, I have opted for the pointer method and am unsure whether this is a "good" method or "good practice".

Comment: Pointers and references both work with polymorphism. The problem was in the part of the code you didn't show to us.

Comment: *"code, however, does not work if AccSensor is passed by reference"* This code has no references. Are you showing the code that works? You should show the broken one.

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] of the code that doesn't work, and copy-paste it into your question. Also copy-paste (as text) the full and complete build-log. And add comments in the shown code where you get the errors.

Comment: You're replacing pointers with references, but for some reason you replaced `Accelerometer *acc;` with `Accelerometer acc;` is not a reference. Read about object slicing. Also, I suggest pinging users with `@username` in a comment when you've made an edit in response to their comment. Otherwise they're likely to not see it.

Comment: *As a result, I have opted for the pointer method and am unsure whether this is a "good" method or "good practice".*  Sure, it is good practice.  You may want to add a comment to it's member variable indicating that the pointer is non-owning, and cannot be null.

Comment: Thanks @HolyBlackCat I was not aware that this could be an issue. I'll have a look into object slicing.

Comment: *The code, however, does not work if AccSensor is passed by reference rather than by pointer* It doesn't matter if something is passed by reference if you immediately make a copy of it, as in `Handler(Accelerometer &a){ acc = a; }`. `acc` is not a reference. Why do you expect it to work polymorphically?

Comment: Ah, I was unaware I was using references completely wrong and will have another look into their proper usage. Cheers. @n.m.couldbeanAI

Comment: The `&` operator in `&acc` is the ***pointer-to*** operator. It creates a pointer. In your case a pointer to `AccSensor`, i.e. `AccSensor*` which is convertible to `Accelerometer*`. The erroneous code, besides the object-slicing issue, have `Handler(Accelerometer &a)` where `a`  is a reference and not a pointer. You can't pass a pointer as argument.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I've had a brief look into object slicing and since it's being passed as a reference this is how I understand it would work:
- acc in Handler should have access to the methods defined in Accelerometer but not AccSensor due to slicing
- acc defined in main() can still use all implemented methods as it's unaffected by the slicing

Do I have this understood correctly?

Comment: Yes, sounds correct. You have to use references or pointers all the way (both as class member and as function parameters), otherwise you get slicing. You can use them interchangably, e.g. it's recommended to have pointers as class members, because references make classes non-assignable by default due to being non-(re)assignable themselves, but you might still want to use references as function parameters to get a cleaner call syntax and indicate that you don't want null pointers.

Comment: You absolutely should get used to implement the object's initialiser list (not to be confused with `std::initializer_list`): `Handler(Accelerometer* a) : acc(a) { }` – this prefers direct initialisation by value over default initialisation + assignment – the latter can in some cases have a significant performance penalty. More important, though: Some types *only* can be initialised this way – and this comprises *references* as well! Further such types are e.g. `const` members or non-default-constructible types.